# Remove/Unset content of CMS page

Tags: php, magento2.2, xml

I have created a custom module which shows some custom product listing and banner data. I have created a system setting to set those things in homepage or use default one. Now what i want if admin select use custom module homepage then existing content will be unset or remove and new content will be shown. below is my cms_index_index code. which insert that block in cms page content area and things come up but how can i remove existing content before showing those things.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>


        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Hello\Pageconfig\Block\Pageconfig" ifconfig="pageconfig/settings/use" name="hello.configured.homepage"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```